# Getting Parent div's width to equal widest Child element/div

Tags: javascript, css, svg

To my understanding, if a div's width and height properties are not defined, the Parent div will equal the result of the arranged children elements width and height properties added collectively (and respectively).

My current set up is like so:

```
<div> //container
  <div> //list of each element
    <div> // element 1
      ... children comprised of on SVG and a few other divs
    </div>
    <div> // element 2
      ... children comprised of on SVG and a few other divs
    </div>
    <div> // element 3
      ... children comprised of on SVG and a few other divs
    </div>
    …etc…
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the `width`s of the element divs are not getting set (or updated) correctly.   The width of the div should be the width of the child SVG (as it is the widest),  and the height of the div should be the height of the child divs (2 of them) and the height of the SVG.

Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HCJYh/) of the example.  You will notice that the bar example is being cut off.  This div's computed width is 300, despite its SVG is larger (drag to see the remaining portion)

JQ-UI is in play, so after a user manipulates the size of on representation, the others will re-render themselves.   If we can figure out why the div is rendering to 300px, then it will also fix the re-rendering, since it will be based on its children elements.

It appears that the issue might also be with the SVGs themselves.  I have not defined the width and height properties on the SVG, rather I did so on the CSS.  If I manipulate the SVG width propertuy on resize, it appears to potentially work, but I am still uynsure of why the SVG's width is not calcualated and then fit into the div.

Comment: You show some code here, but something different and more complex on the fiddle demo, please narrow the code on the fiddle demo to indicate the problem itself.

Comment: the part i dont get is how without jquery i think, outer div stays the size of content but when reaches parent it stays to size of parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does lie with the SVG.   The attribute must be defined within the HTML tag inline, not by CSS.   This seems weird, but by setting the SVG attributes here, JQ-UI will then adjust the SVG property here, but if there wasn't one to begin with, the browser determines its original dimensions.

```
<div> //container
  <div> //list of each element
    <div> // element 1
      <svg width="300px" height="100px"></svg>
    </div>
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

When a `<div>` does not have its width and height defined, both properties are set to `auto`.

When a block-level element, like `<div>`, has a width of `auto`, it will expand to the available horizontal space in its containing element. If its children are wider, than the specification says they should protrude out, but they won't affect the width of the parent. (There was a nasty IE bug back in the day that didn't follow this specification that made floated layouts very difficult to implement).

When a block-level element, like `<div>`, has a height of auto, it will expand vertically to contain all of its children that are in document flow.

You'll need to change the default behaviour. For each parent you want to expand, and each of its children, you will need to apply `display:inline-block;`

```
 div.parent, div.child1, div.child2{
       display:inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get div wrong. Div elements are block elements and block elements expand to the width of parent width.

You could use flex box model.

Use inline-box.

Use Jquery to define width.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/DVhQA/

```
<div class='m'> 
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

then

```
div {
    border:solid;
    /* overflow:auto; */
    display:inline-block;
}

div>div {
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
div>div:first-of-type{
    width:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Each parent container has "display:inline:block", so that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with div `measure-container-c30`.

It has class with width being set to 89%.

Which is weird if you want space around the div use **margin.**

Do this:

1. Remove all width style on `measurec29` div.
2. Remove `width: 89%;` `overflow: auto;` on `measure-container-c30` div.
3. Remove width on `measure-rep-container-c29` div.